# jQuery Javascript not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been trying to add my custom jQuery script to wordpress, the script code and all is working on jsfiddle when I choose the jquery library, but when I'm trying to add it on wordpress it is not working.
Here's how added the wp enqueue code:

```
function cb_scroller() {

//wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_register_script( 'scroller', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroller.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );

wp_enqueue_script( 'scroller' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cb_scroller' );
```

So what may be the problem?
here's the jsfiddle attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/naimelhajj/q4bdfcwb/
(disregard the styling, I've imported the css and js as "external resources")

Comment: Try to take a look in console log if you do not have any errors with $ sign. If this is the case change all the code from scroller.js from $ sign to use jQuery instead. Instead of $(".arrow-left") you will have this jQuery(".arrow-left") and so on for other selectors

Comment: at what time is the action added? it is possible it is added at a time where the scripts have already been enqueued. this is not specified. Also look for any errors in your browser

Answer (score 2):

This is your script (which you should have posted in the question)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow-left").click(function(){
        $(".site-main-gluten").animate({scrollLeft: "-="+100});
    });
    $(".arrow-right").click(function(){
        $(".site-main-gluten").animate({scrollLeft: "+="+100});
    });        
});
```

Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default, which means `$` is not defined, it has to be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".arrow-left").click(function(){
        $(".site-main-gluten").animate({scrollLeft: "-="+100});
    });
    $(".arrow-right").click(function(){
        $(".site-main-gluten").animate({scrollLeft: "+="+100});
    });        
});
```